# Woocommerce multiple categories - Which one is displayed?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with Woocommerce. My shop page shows the product categories. But when I have a product in multiple categories, there is only one category displayed, and it seems to be the first one alphabetically.
Instead, I need Woocommerce to display the highest category (or in my case, the lowest category ID, since I organised created the categories in the right order). I have included a link. http://www.jointdeseuil.fr/
Please, can anyone help? Currently the code is like this :

`<?php 
list($firstpart) = explode('|', $product_cats); 
echo $firstpart; 
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to know what the rest of your code is.... what is `$product_cats`? what is `$firstpart`?

Without that, I'll show how to get the product categories from scratch using `wc_get_product_terms()`

```
global $product;
$product_cats = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat', array( 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'fields' => 'all' ) );
if( $product_cats ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach( $product_cats as $cat ){
        printf( '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', esc_url( get_term_link( $cat ) ), $cat->name );
   }
   echo '</ul>';
}
```

or if you don't need any special ordering you can use a default WordPress function

```
global $product;
echo get_the_term_list( $product->id, 'product_cat', __( 'Categories: ', 'text-domain' ), ', ' );
```